# My app drains battery even that I release wake lock

Tags: android, battery, proximity, wakelock

I'm building a simple app that has `BroadcastReciever` that listens to PHONE_STATE:

```
        <receiver android:name=".PhoneStateBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

In the `BroadcastReciever`'s `onRecieve()` I start a service when the state is `OFFHOOK` and stop the service when the state is `IDLE`:

```
public class PhoneStateBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        String state = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
            context.startService(new Intent(context, ProximityService.class));
        }
        else if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
            context.stopService(new Intent(context, ProximityService.class));
        }
    }

}
```

In the service I'm registering proximity sensor listener, and creating a `WakeLock` so the screen will turn off well while on call.
After the call ends I stop the service, and in its `onDestroy()` I'm unregistering the listener and release the `WakeLock`.
But it seems that something is not releasing out there because I see a huge battery drain from my app (30%).

I put a Log when the listener unregistering and also on the `WakeLock` release, and I can see that the `WakeLock` is released and the listener is unregistered successfully (I can also see the Log from `SensorManager` that the listener is unregistered).

What am I missing here?
That's really annoying.

Some code of the service:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){

    Log.d("CALL", "Service started");

    // Get an instance of the sensor service, and use that to get an instance of
    // a particular sensor.
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mProximity = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY);

    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mProximity, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

    mAudioManager = (AudioManager)this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    mPowerMngr = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    try{
        mWakeLock = mPowerMngr.newWakeLock(PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK, "Proximity");

        if (!mWakeLock.isHeld()) {
            Log.d("CALL", "Wake lock acquired");
            mWakeLock.acquire();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        mWakeLock = null;
    }


    return START_STICKY;
}

public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);

    if (mWakeLock != null) {
        if (mWakeLock.isHeld()) {
            Log.d("CALL", "Wake lock released");
            mWakeLock.release();
        }
    }


            Log.d("CALL", "Service stopped");
    }
```

The log I see:

```
09-30 03:35:09.120: D/SensorManager(21565): unregisterListener:: disable all sensors for this listener,  listener = com.eladaharon.android.proximity.ProximityService@41a31a18
09-30 03:35:09.125: D/CALL(21565): Wake lock released
09-30 03:35:09.125: D/CALL(21565): Service stopped
```

Thanks a lot!
Elad

Answer (score 1):

If your service is receiving multiple intents, your code will create a new `WakeLock` each time `onStartCommand` is executed. You would be releasing only the last `WakeLock` and leaking the others, which would explain the battery drain. Logcat will normally provide helpful messages in this situation.

Since your service remains running for a time, you could check whether `mWakeLock` is initialized before calling `newWakeLock()`.